# $a_{1}=4, a_{2}=12, a_{n+1} = 4a_{n} -2a_{n-1}$. Find the explicit formula for $a_{n}$ and prove it using induction.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a_{n}$ be a sequence defined recursively by $a_{1}=4, a_{2}=12, a_{n+1} = 4a_{n} -2a_{n-1}$. Find the explicit formula for $a_{n}$ and prove it using induction.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I mean I have tried to find the formula but it is really hard. I have the sequence like (1,4), (2,12), (3,40), (4,136), and (5,464), but I can't think of a pattern

Comment: I have given a short answer, you should read the link.  Not easy to guess the general form in such cases, though its not hard to solve using the method in the link.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the answer is indeed (sqrt(2) +2)^n +(2-sqrt(2))^n so yeah

Answer (score 1):

OK, you have the wiki link above which is elaborate. In a nutshell, these are linear homogeneous recurrences, for which the substitution $a_n \to x^n$ does the trick.  Using this in the recurrence, you get for all $n >2$,

$$x^{n+1}=4x^n-2x^{n-1}$$
$$\iff x^{n-1}(x^2-4x+2)=0$$
$$\iff x^2-4x+2=0 \implies x =2\pm\sqrt2$$

As the recurrence is linear, linear combinations of solutions are themselves solutions, so in general we could have $a_n = C_1(2+\sqrt2)^n + C_2(2-\sqrt2)^n$.  Use the initial values to find $C_1, C_2$ and use induction to prove uniqueness as asked.

Comment: how would i prove it by induction

Answer (score 1):

A more elementary argument of why the "solving polynomial of $x$" trick will work.

What we essentially want is to reduce the degree of $n$.
What we do here is find $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $a_{n+1}-x_1a_n=x_2(a_n-x_1a_{n-1})$. Once that is done we can let $b_n=a_n-x_1a_{n-1}$ so that $b_{n+1}=x_2b_n$ and that is easy as $b_2=a_2-x_1a_1$ and thus $b_n=(a_2-x_1a_1)\cdot (x_2)^{n-2}$.

To solve $a_n$ knowing $b_n$, we use the simple technique of summing up.
$a_2-x_1a_{1}=a_2-x_1a_{1}$ (constant)
$a_3-x_1a_{2}=(a_2-x_1a_{1})\cdot x_2$
$a_4-x_1a_{3}=(a_2-x_1a_{1})\cdot {x_2}^2$
...
$a_n-x_1a_{n-1}=(a_2-x_1a_{1})\cdot {x_2}^{n-2}$

We multiply the first equation by ${x_1}^{n-2}$, second equation by ${x_1}^{n-1}$ and so on and sum them up to reach $a_n-{x_1}^{n-1}a_1=(a_2-x_1a_1)({x_1}^{n-2}+{x_1}^{n-1}x_2+...+{x_1}{x_2}^{n-1}+{x_2}^{n-2})=(a_2-x_1a_1)(\frac{{x_2}^n-{x_1}^n}{x_2-x_1})$

In order to find $x_1$ and $x_2$, we rearrange $a_{n+1}-x_1a_n=x_2(a_n-x_1a_{n-1})$ to one side so $a_{n+1}-(x_1+x_2)a_n+x_1x_2a_{n-1}=0$ and we know from this $x_1+x_2=4$ amd $x_1x_2=2$. This is why we are solving $x^2-4x+2=0$.

Comment: okay, and so how would we prove it by induction

Comment: Proof by induction is simple once you know the formula. Assume the formula holds for all $i\leq k$ and calculate $4a_k-2a_{k-1}$. This should be the same number as directly calculated $a_{k+1}$ using the formula.